# Android App Problem (not running)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mobile

Anyone got any Idea why this code is not working, It was working fine until I tried to install the Google AdMob Ads SDK then all of a sudden the app crashes every time it I try and run it.

```
package co.miniz.RageToonViewer;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;
import co.miniz.RageToonViewer.R;
import co.miniz.RageToonViewer.ImageNumbers;
import co.miniz.RageToonViewer.NoRepeatRandom;
import co.miniz.RageToonViewer.Download;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RageToonViewerActivity extends Activity {
FileReader reader;
URL url;
Download DL;
NoRepeatRandom randGen;
ImageNumbers noOfImages;
ImageView imView;
Gallery g;
Text text1;
Bitmap bmImg;
TextView tv;
AssetManager assetManager;
int random;
int prevRand = -10;
int noOfFiles ;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        assetManager = getAssets();
        DL = new Download();
        imView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mainImage);
        imView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);

        //----- Get Number OF Images -----
        noOfImages = new ImageNumbers();
        noOfFiles = noOfImages.GetNumber();

        //----- Set Button and Text outPut for testing -----
        Button button1main = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
        tv.setText("Click above for a random RageToon!");


        //----- Generate Random Number -----
        randGen = new NoRepeatRandom(0, noOfFiles);
        random = randGen.GetRandom();

        //----- Set First Image -----
        imView.setImageBitmap(GetImage());

        //----- Set up Button Click Action -----
        button1main.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tv.setText("Click above for a random RageToon!" + noOfFiles);
                noOfFiles = noOfImages.GetNumber();
                imView.setImageBitmap(GetImage());
            }
         });

        imView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                tv.setText("Click above for a random RageToon!" + noOfFiles);
                noOfFiles = noOfImages.GetNumber();
                imView.setImageBitmap(GetImage());
            }
        });
} 

public Bitmap GetImage() {

    random = randGen.GetRandom();
    URL tempURL = null;
    try {
        tempURL = new URL("http://miniz.co/RageToonApp/Images/" + random + ".jpg");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    Bitmap TempImage = DL.getRemoteImage(tempURL, tv);

    if (TempImage == null)
    {
        TempImage = GetImage();
    }
   return TempImage;
}
}
```

When Debugging I can see an java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo in the LogCat view.

Thanks for any Help ! 
Ross.

edit :  From LogCat

```
07-17 01:35:14.680: WARN/dalvikvm(3540): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40023160)
07-17 01:35:14.680: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
07-17 01:35:14.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{co.miniz.RageToonViewer/co.miniz.RageToon.RageToonViewerActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: co.miniz.RageToon.RageToonViewerActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@458a4278
07-17 01:35:14.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2424)
07-17 01:35:14.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2519)
07-17 01:35:14.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:123)
07-17 01:35:14.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1870)
07-17 01:35:14.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-17 01:35:14.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-17 01:35:14.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4370)
07-17 01:35:14.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-17 01:35:14.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-17 01:35:14.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-17 01:35:14.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-17 01:35:14.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-17 01:35:14.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: co.miniz.RageToon.RageToonViewerActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@458a4278
07-17 01:35:14.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
07-17 01:35:14.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
07-17 01:35:14.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
07-17 01:35:14.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
07-17 01:35:14.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
07-17 01:35:14.770: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3540):     ... 11 more
07-17 01:35:14.890: ERROR/SemcCheckin(3540): Get crash dump level : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/semc-checkin/crashdump
07-17 01:35:14.900: WARN/ActivityManager(1146): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.sonyericsson.android.jcrashcatcher.action.BUGREPORT_AUTO cmp=com.sonyericsson.android.jcrashcatcher/.JCrashCatcherService (has extras) }: not found
07-17 01:35:15.000: INFO/Process(1146): Sending signal. PID: 3540 SIG: 3
07-17 01:35:15.000: INFO/dalvikvm(3540): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
07-17 01:35:15.000: ERROR/dalvikvm(3540): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
07-17 01:35:15.060: ERROR/SemcCheckin(1681): Get Crash Level : java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/semc-checkin/crashdump
07-17 01:35:15.170: DEBUG/dalvikvm(2189): GC freed 264 objects / 16000 bytes in 32ms
07-17 01:35:19.036: WARN/jdwp(3540): Debugger is telling the VM to exit with code=1
```

I have found out that every app I now create in eclipse that uses any for of connection to the internet will now crash when I try and run it on my phone ?
They also crash when I use the code:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

I hope this will help in determining what has gone wrong.

Comment: You've bundled three different crashes into one question. Just uninstall the app and reinstall from fresh.

Comment: Connection to the internet, that needs the INTERNET permission in your manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requestWindowFeature()` must be called before `setContentView()` (but after `super.onCreate()`)

As Blundell mentioned, to connect to the internet you need the `INTERNET` permission, place `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` outside the `<application>` but inside the `<manifest>` tags in the Manifest file.

Not sure about the crash, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean project if you are using eclipse.
Uninstall app from whatever device you are using and then try once. this happened to me as well. Uninstalling and re installing worked..